# Device token and push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, push, token, device

I'm currently creating an app that needs to receive push notifications from a server. This app has a facebook connect part, and a logout (from facebook) part as well.

When I get the device token, I send it to my server and save it into DB with the FB_id, then when I want to send a notification to a user, I get its FB_id, and then get its device token.

My question is:

If a user decides to lend its device to a friend, I will have two FB_id for one device token. Then, the first user will receive notifications from the second one...

How can I deal with this?

I thought to delete the token on logout, but I'm not sure it's really safe...

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I thought to delete the token on logout, but I'm not sure it's really safe" WHy not safe? Seems to me you should be doing this

Comment: Because imagine you logout without clicking on logout (uninstalling the app for example), the tokens won't be deleted. Am I wrong?

Comment: But then when the fried logs in you overwrite the fbid for the device token. "..will have two FB_id for one device token." IMO you should avoid this situation. If the fried doesn't log in then the app shouldn't respond to the push if sent to the old fbid.